# AuthReply: I HATE YOU response while using git cvsimport

Tags: cvs2git

I am migrating from CVS to Git. I am trying the following command on Cygwin Terminal

```
$ git cvsimport -v -d :pserver:kashif.nazar@cvs-server:/cvsroot MyModule
```

but I am getting the following response.

```
AuthReply: I HATE YOU
```

Seems like this is an authentication issue.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think git just needs some candy. Don't take it personal... It happens to the best of us

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log in via CVS first:

```
cvs -d :pserver:kashif.nazar@cvs-server:/cvsroot login
```

You'll need your pserver password (often it's just "guest" or an empty string).

Comment: there should be space after -d  "cvs -d :pserver:kashif.nazar@cvs-server:/cvsroot login"

Comment: When I do this, I get a prompt for CVS password but the password is displayed in text and is treated as a command. What can I do?